QtCreator: missing shortcut for switching between widgets
For example (in QtCreator) using Ctrl-F to find a piece of text in the opened file – the focus switches from files to search box, I enter the searched text, I enter ENTER, and if existent, the file view is scrolled to the next position of found text, and that found text is highlighted.
My question: how (just by a key sequence) to switch the focus from the search box to the opened file?
In general I am missing keyboard shortcuts to switch between side bars, panes and screens of QtCreator.
Ctrl-Tab, Ctrl-E and Tab are ony partial solutions for that problem.
And Ctrl-F, Shift-Ctrl-F, Shift-Ctrl-U and so on seem to be just one-direction focus changers, each to the regarding widget (find in open file, find in project files, find usage of a named programming item).
I did not find regarding hints within the QtCreator manual, not within QtCreator's shortcut configuration, nor here, until now.
